# Why should i use Rails.logger instead of logger in my model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, log4r

I am a newbie to rails.  I am using log4r for logging.  I observed that when i use just logger in my models, it doesn't work.  But if i use Rails.logger the logs are coming fine.  Why is it happening?  Please help me to understand.

```
  def self.create_user_from_params(auth_params)
    Rails.logger.debug "auth params are ";
    return nil;
  end
```

works.   But if i use

```
  def self.create_user_from_params(auth_params)
    logger.debug "auth params are ";
    return nil;
  end
```

it doesn't work.  Here is my log4r yml

```
log4r_config:
  # define all loggers ...
  loggers:
    - name      : production
      level     : INFO
      trace     : 'false'
      outputters :
      - datefile
    - name      : development
      level     : DEBUG
      trace     : 'true'
      outputters :
      - datefile

  # define all outputters (incl. formatters)
  outputters:
  - type: DateFileOutputter
    name: datefile
    dirname: "log"
    filename: "server.log" # notice the file extension is needed!
    formatter:
      date_pattern: '%H:%M:%S'
      pattern     : '%d %l: %m '
      type        : PatternFormatter
```

**update** I just remembered that i had added 'config.active_record.logger = Logger.new("log/sql.log")' in my config/application.rb

I used that as i wanted to log my sqls to separate file. Now i got another question.
How to log sqls to separate file without changing config.active_record.logger?

Comment: Are the logs being appended to server.log?

Comment: No.  If i just use logger.info/logger.debug it doesnt go to server.log.  If i use Rail.logger then it goes to server.log

Comment: It looks like you are not using log4r -- you're just using the default logger. My recommendation: don't spend time on this -- spend time on features that matter, and when you've learned more about Rails, come back and tackle the configuration and use of the logger.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [in-depth tutorial on how to use Log4r](http://blog.mmlac.com/log4r-for-rails/).

Specifically your issue can be solved by setting config.logger to Log4r::Logger["development"] (and therefore Rails.logger will log to Log4r) or specifying logger = Log4r::Logger["development"] in the files you want to use "logger".  Setting the config.logger flag however should work with Rails.logger.debug as well as logger.debug.

SQL in a separate file is also described in detail in the linked blogpost. Basically you use the Rails Notification Pipeline and write to a custom logger that logs to another file.